# Optimize a function that ensures an object's properties does not have any of these values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, conditional-statements

I have an array of objects that represent form fields. I want to make sure that none of the elements in the array have their initial values. As in all fields need to be updated. The initial value is below. I'd like a simple function that checks each element and ensures none of these properties have the default fields.

```
[
  {
    key: 0,
    name: '',
    typeLabel: '',
    typeValue: 0,
    value: '',
  }
  ...
]
```

Looking for help on improving this

```
collection.every((obj) => {
  if (obj.key === 0) return false;
  if (obj.name === '') return false;
  if (obj.typeLabel === '') return false;
  if (obj.typeValue === 0) return false;
  if (obj.value === '') return false;
  return true;
});
```

EDIT: Actually just thought of this

```
collection.every((obj) => {
  const values = Object.values(obj);
  return values.includes(0, '');
});
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you hitting any specific problems?

Comment: @snek He wants to improve the code.

Comment: If you're talking about perf, the first codeblock will be faster. It is also *way* more obvious what your intent is. JavaScript engines optimize idiomatic code, so just write idiomatic code.

Answer (score -2):

To be honest I'm not sure how much more better you can make it, it looks pretty decent to me!  Any changes I'd make would be subjective changes that don't actually matter. Curious what other people will answer with though, maybe I'm missing something :)

I mean you could do this and it's arguably less if/elses and uses a named function to explain what it is doing which is *maybe* nicer? But meh I don't think this matters all that much:

```
function inputValueHasBeenSet(inputObject) {
  return !!inputObject.key && 
    !!inputObject.name && 
    !!inputObject.typeLabel && 
    !!inputObject.typeValue && 
    !!inputObject.value;
}

collection.every(inputValueHasBeenSet);
```

Comment: They're explicitly trying to check `0` and `''`. This will extend to any falsey value.

Comment: A fair point. I'd argue that it's not like someone filling out a form is going to set a value to `null` or `undefined`, and if they set `name `explicitly to a string of `0` that would be truthy. I imagine that in a normal world use case this would work.

Comment: That said, as you can probably surmise by the tone of my answer, I don't feel super strongly opinionated on the matter.